# Existence of Dichlorine Pentoxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecules, halides

I searched the net and a lot of books, but I was unable to find any information about dichlorine pentoxide.

1. Does dichlorine pentoxide($\ce{Cl2O5}$) exist?
2. If it doesn't exist, then why so?
3. If dibromine pentoxide and iodine pentoxide do exit, then why not dichlorine pentoxide?

Comment: I've never heard of this site, but [here](http://www.endmemo.com/chem/compound/cl2o5.php) it is with a couple example reactions for what it's worth ;)

Comment: [Here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Mtth5g59dEIC&pg=PA463&lpg=PA463&dq=dichlorine+pentoxide&source=bl&ots=tE0OlvM2VA&sig=BV3mFUvUA3UYn-c5zLRtj9jspR4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ9_vzuIXSAhXGvI8KHW8jCGs4ChDoAQgdMAA#v=onepage&q=dichlorine%20pentoxide&f=false), it says it is unknown at present.

Comment: That is a pretty old book though (Published in 2001).

Comment: Ok , for once lets agree that Dichlorine Pentoxide doesnt exist. 

Then why is that so?

Dibromine pentoxide(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dibromine_pentoxide) and Iodine Pentoxide does exit, then why not Dichlorine Pentoxide?

Comment: I've seen this reaction given in half a dozen websites I've never heard of before: $\ce{Cl2O5 + H2O -> 2HClO3}$. The only one with any discussion is in Russian and I'm trying to find someone who can read that. It's just a couple sentences though. I've also seen it mentioned in nomenclature lessons, i.e. "$\ce{Cl2O5}$ chlorine dioxide from chloric oxide (V)" . Still nothing solid about it though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The crux of [this](https://distant-lessons.ru/kisloty-xlora.html) (Russian) article is that $\ce{Cl2O5}$ is not stable enough to be isolated in a pure form, and if it were, it would be strongly acidic oxidizer.

[This web site](http://www.endmemo.com/chem/compound/cl2o5.php) is representative of several others that simply give example reactions of the compound (the second reaction being the most common exampe):

$$\ce{NiCl2 + 3O2 -> NiO + Cl2O5}$$
$$\ce{H2O + Cl2O5 -> 2HClO3}$$

The statement in the first article and the simple fact that there is such a dearth of information about this compound suggest that it really only exists as a transient, unstable, oxidizing acid that apparently has not been isolated as a stable compound.  Furthermore, information can be found in Wikipedia and/or PubChem for $\ce{Cl2O_x}$, where $x \in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7$.